# Lazy loading works for loading data, but not when filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, lazy-loading

Here the first script is written for lazy loading the table data and the second script is written for filtering with lazy loading but the second one is not working.

I have a Codeigniter report in which I did some filtering on the table data. I am using jQuery AJAX to lazy load data. What I expected is that when I fetch the data with a filter the lazy loading is not working. Shall i use first script for both table load by default and for filter. i am getting confusion. Can anyone please tell me how to merge both script as a single script for both. Please help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#filter').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    title: ('&nbsp;') + '<button type="button" class="close pull-right" data-dismiss="alert"  style="color:black;">&times;</button>',
    html: true,
    content: $('#customdiv').html()
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".popover .close", function() {
    $(this).parents(".popover").popover('hide');
  });

  var limit = 20;
  var start = 0;
  var action = 'inactive';

  function lazzy_loader(limit) {
    var output = '';
    for (var count = 0; count < limit; count++) {
      output += '<tr class="post_data">';
      output += '</tr>';
    }
    $('#load_data_message').html(output);
  }

  lazzy_loader(limit);

  function search_fields(limit, start) {
    $(".spinner").show();

    $.ajax({
      url: "<?=base_url()?>missed_call_campaign/fetch_data",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        limit: limit,
        start: start
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $(".spinner").hide();
        if (data == '') {
          $('#load_data_message').html('<p class="content-desc">No More Data Found</p>');
          action = 'active';
        } else {
          $('#load_data').append(data);
          $('#load_data_message').html("");
          action = 'inactive';
        }
      }
    });
  }

  if (action == 'inactive') {
    action = 'active';
    search_fields(limit, start);
  }

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive') {
      lazzy_loader(limit);
      action = 'active';
      start = start + limit;
      setTimeout(function() {
        search_fields(limit, start);
      }, 100);
    }
  });
});

function subcategory() {
  var ClickedCategory = new Array();

  $('.CategoryClicked').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      ClickedCategory.push($(this).val());
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?=base_url()?>missed_call_campaign/subcategory_checkbox",
    data: {
      type: 'text',
      ClickedCategory: ClickedCategory
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $("#collapsepp").hide();
      $("#collapseqq").html(response);
    }
  });
}

function subsource() {
  var ClickedSource = new Array();
  $('.SourceClicked').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      ClickedSource.push($(this).val());
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?=base_url()?>missed_call_campaign/subsource_checkbox",
    data: {
      type: 'text',
      ClickedSource: ClickedSource
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $("#collapserr").hide();
      $("#collapsess").html(response);
    }
  });
}

function clearFilter() {
  location.reload();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#data_filter", function() {
    var CheckedRep = new Array();
    var ClickedStatus = new Array();
    var ClickedType = new Array();
    var ClickedCategory = new Array();
    var ClickedSubCategory = new Array();
    var ClickedSubCategory_Filter = new Array();
    var ClickedSource = new Array();
    var ClickedSubSource = new Array();
    var ClickedSubSource_Filter = new Array();

    $('.RepClicked').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        CheckedRep.push($(this).val());
      }
    });

    $('.StatusClicked').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        ClickedStatus.push($(this).val());
      }
    });

    $('.TypeClicked').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        ClickedType.push($(this).val());
      }
    });

    $('.CategoryClicked').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        ClickedCategory.push($(this).val());
      }
    });

    $('.SourceClicked').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        ClickedSource.push($(this).val());
      }
    });

    $('.SubSourceClicked').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        ClickedSubSource.push($(this).val());
      }
    });

    $('.SubCategoryClicked').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        ClickedSubCategory.push($(this).val());
      }
    });

    $('.SubCategoryChecked_Filter').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        ClickedSubCategory_Filter.push($(this).val());
      }
    });

    $('.SubSourceClicked_filter').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        ClickedSubSource_Filter.push($(this).val());
      }
    });

    if ((CheckedRep.length > 0) || (ClickedStatus.length > 0) || (ClickedType.length > 0) || (ClickedCategory.length > 0)
      (ClickedSource.length > 0) || (ClickedSubSource.length > 0) || (ClickedSubCategory.length > 0) ||
      (ClickedSubCategory_Filter.length > 0) || (ClickedSubSource_Filter.length > 0)) {
      var limits = 20;
      var starts = 0;
      var actions = 'inactive';

      lazzy_loading(limits);

      if (actions == 'inactive') {
        actions = 'active';
        filter_data(limits, starts, CheckedRep, ClickedStatus, ClickedType, ClickedCategory, ClickedSubCategory, ClickedSubCategory_Filter,
          ClickedSource, ClickedSubSource, ClickedSubSource_Filter);
      }

      $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data_filter").height() && actions == 'inactive') {
          lazzy_loading(limits);
          actions = 'active';
          starts = starts + limits;
          setTimeout(function() {
            filter_data(limits, starts, CheckedRep, ClickedStatus, ClickedType, ClickedCategory, ClickedSubCategory, ClickedSubCategory_Filter,
              ClickedSource, ClickedSubSource, ClickedSubSource_Filter);
          }, 100);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  function lazzy_loading(limits) {
    var output = '';
    for (var counts = 0; counts < limits; counts++) {
      output += '<tr class="post_data">';
      output += '</tr>';
    }
    $('#load_data_filter').html(output);
  }

  function filter_data(limits, starts, CheckedRep, ClickedStatus, ClickedType, ClickedCategory, ClickedSubCategory, ClickedSubCategory_Filter,
    ClickedSource, ClickedSubSource, ClickedSubSource_Filter) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?=base_url()?>missed_call_campaign/toDoAjax",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        type: 'text',
        CheckedRep: CheckedRep,
        ClickedStatus: ClickedStatus,
        ClickedType: ClickedType,
        ClickedCategory: ClickedCategory,
        ClickedSource: ClickedSource,
        ClickedSubSource: ClickedSubSource,
        ClickedSubCategory: ClickedSubCategory,
        ClickedSubCategory_Filter: ClickedSubCategory_Filter,
        ClickedSubSource_Filter: ClickedSubSource_Filter,
        limits: limits,
        starts: starts
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(response) {
        $(".spinner").hide();
        $("#load_data").hide();

        if (response == '') {
          $('#load_data_message').html('<p class="content-desc">No More Data Found123</p>');
          action = 'active';
        } else {
          $('#load_data_filter').append(response);
          $('#load_data_message').html("");
          action = 'inactive';
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to reinitialize the lazy load after success you fetched data from the back end.

Comment: sorry sir i didn't get you where i have to reinitialize??, in the first or in second script. Thanks for your reply sir

Comment: Hi, you have to reinitialize the after  when filter script successfully execute and the data is fetch.

Comment: sir can you please show me in code. so that i ll come to know sir..

Comment: I will share later. currently i am little busy sorry for delay.

Comment: K sir. Thanku for your reply sir.

Comment: sir you are free means can you please share the code.